# will anyone stop laughing n thinking im crazy long enough to see theres a major problem(s) in my house?

Tags: new-home

As the title suggests, i have many issues in the home i purchased two years ago. And although, couuuntless hours attempting to unravel the mystery, and thhhhousands of dollars to fix the problems i have encountered, it all  mostly made everything worse because no workmen will listen, they just get this smile on their face, then take my money after doing little work/investigating or nothing at all.

Okay, so

1. there is drainage issues. The previous owner installed a "french drain" that i recently learned runs over 30 feet underground to a nearby street opening. I say "french drain" because when i had it cleaned out, the workman said he had never seen a french drain set up this way, but it was clear to him that someone had designed and attempted to create a multi channel french drain like system, and had failed. miserably. 
   it cost $400 to have it "cleaned" so that standing water n rotten smelling muck werent coming up from the drain grates. that lasted ONE DAY, and it was full again, i dont know where the water originates when its not raining, but when it does, water pools out from the drain n alllll over my garden n underneath the foundation slab.
2. I tested the tap water and it failed twice for colliform bacteria, so i since had a whole house water filtration with uv sanitation installed. Although, the workmen put the devices inside of a large plastic shed, in that same area of garden that gets drenched from the french drain muck. i tried to explain why that wasnt a good spot, but was told, "honey go inside n let me do my job. i think i know a lil more about this than you do."
   i opened the shed earlier today n found what looks like "nests" of rodents in between the osmosis chambers, and droppings alll ontop of all the chamber components.    that cost me $5200 to buy.
3. The rats. i learned last year there were "roof rats" above my otherwise verrry clean home, and hired a rodent removal company. they tried to get me to leave the insulation n just spray it with disinfectants. I told the man that if i saw a pile of dog poop in my yard, id get gloves n pick it up, not just spray perfume on it and leave it. and this is myyy houuse, and its rattttt poop...  I most definetly wanted all the insulation and everything possibly contaminated to be removed, disinfected, then replaced. For $8,000 they removed half the insulation by hand, shoving it into trash bags and then throwing it down to my hallway floor to be collected and then thrown in dumpster. My house was built in 1952, i have since learned there was asbestos in the very first layer of insulation. The workmen commented on how many differing layers there were but failed to identify the danger. Since the attic is very small, they "couldnt fit" suction hoses, and left more than half the insulation still intact, telling me not to worry the "disinfectant" would kill any parasites. 
   They didnt clean the attic floor before they shot fiberglass onto the infested insulation n asbestos. Sending it into the living space. Where my 6 month old son n i were told it was perfectly okay to sit n play while they worked.

I have since learned that they overfilled the space with fiberglass, blocking the soffit vents, my home sits at 70-80% humidity constantly now, despite multiplex damprids, and dehumidifiers. More than likely over 90-100 in attic space, which has lead to mold n fungus growing inside the walls and under the insulation on the attic floor aka my ceiling.

yes, it is possible to be this screwed over on a damn house. i spent my liffe savings to straight out cash buy it, and now, im terrified to sell n lose all my invested money when i report these facts to any potential buyer. The few workmen who did their job, usually gave me about a $5,000 to $20,000 estimate EACH. (mold guy, attic insulation removal n fix guy, drainage guy to remove french drain n put in gutters, biohazard cleanup guy, hvac guy, inspector guy) Adding up to about $60,000 in estimates, i paid $100,000 to buy the damn house.

Everytime i hire a company it gets worse due to incompentance and ignorance. And i have to pay for it, both monitarily and physically. I worry about my sons health the most, doctors say hes fine, but dont actttually test for anything, they just ask if i take either illegal or prescription meds that are causing my issues. The answer to both is no.

So, heres my question....... 
whhhhhat do i do???? So far the only remaining option ive come up with is a rope and step stool.

Comment: This is not a real question for this site. Instead it is a major rant that is filled with bad grammar and punctuation. There is no convincing reason to leave this open and the one answer that has been posted so far is spot on.

Comment: You might contact a lawyer, and see if there's any legal action you can take against the folks who have done work in your home.

Answer (score 4):

You are paying a premium for what you want.  Businesses can and do charge more for doing jobs they don't want to do, to do them differently than they would typically do, or to work with someone they see as difficult.

At the same time, no one is forcing you to do any of this.  If you want someone else to do the work, get multiple bids and take the one you think is the best fit for you.  If you don't like the workers, tell them no and hire someone else or do it yourself.